# Itunes says "I do not have enough access privileges for this operation" how do I fix this?

Tags: itunes, software-recommendation, privacy

A year or so ago I was mucking around in my privacy and shared settings, trying to make it so my computer was "secure" when on a college network. Now with my fiddling i've screwed something up and I am running into problems with my shared files. Any ideas to fix?

Comment: Sounds like you do not have full administrator privileges ? Check your User profile and that the allow user to administer this computer is checked.

Comment: sorry, I should have included that i do have admin privileges checked.

Comment: OK, maybe you clarify your question wrt Sharing and also point out what have you tried so far. Sharing with who ect... the better the question the faster and more accurate the answer. You do not go to a Doctor and say "it hurts- Fix it", you tell him where, how, since when ect.

Comment: ok, well I was reading another entry and it was talking about sharing and permissions. I opened up the more info tab and in the sharing and permissions section under "everyone" it has "custom" selected and won't let me select "read & write". Is there something that causes this?

Comment: finally got it to switch to read&write, however after reboot of itunes the message still appears

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. To avoid getting answers that don't really solve your problem, the question will be put on hold FOR NOW until it can be improved. Please edit your question to make it clearer so we can reopen it. Read [How to Ask](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) for more ideas to improve the question. Confusing questions are closed so they don't attract a scattering of answers before they're in a form that is likely to get a clear answer; your question can be reopened at any time if you or someone on your behalf suitably amends it.

Answer (score 1):

To make changes to Sharing in the Get Info window for iTunes please unlock it first.

There is small lock at bottom right of that window, you will need password to open it.

[image]

You might have to do the [Troubleshooting permissions issues in Mac OS X](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2963)

Comment: Housekeeping :) please check the answer as completed if it worked for you.